# executing a jquery function from server side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

here is my code :

```
string script = "GoNext()";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "next", script, true);
```

client side :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
     function GoNext() {
          $("#wizard").scrollable().next();
     }
});
```

i am getting a console error saying GoNext is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not put the function in  `$(document).ready(function () {` block as its scope becomes within the `ready` block and it is not available in global scope.

```
function GoNext() {
     $("#wizard").scrollable().next();
}
```